# How to get RESTful WebAPI ASP.NET Core from Angular 8?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to know how to get parameters from data file of image in the controller
in HTTP POST function. This is my upload image

HTML:

```
     <div >
            <button mat-button style="color:blue" (click)="onClick()">  
                <mat-icon>file_upload</mat-icon>  
                   image
            </button>  
                <input 
                    type="file" 
                    #fileUpload 
                    id="fileUpload" 
                    name="fileUpload" 
                    multiple="multiple" 
                    accept="image/*" 
                    style="display:none;" 
                    (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"
                    [(ngModel)]="model.img"/>
    </div>
    <img *ngIf="availbule"  [src]="imgURL" style="width: 250px;height: 150px;"/>
</div>

<button (click)="uploadFiles()"mat-raised-button 
[disabled]="NumberModel.errors||Company.errors||BridgeWidth.errors
||LengthOfRod.errors||LensWidth.errors">add</button>
```

this is the function that create fromdata and send to the service
ts:

```
 uploadFile(file) {
 {
 var arr= this.fileToUpLoud.name.split('/');

 let ima=arr[arr.length-1];
 const fn=new FormData();
 fn.append('image',ima);
 this.modelService.upload(fn).subscribe();}
```

this is the service that send to server
service:

```
public upload(file:FormData):Observable<void>{
    return this.httpClient.post<void>("/api/Model/",file);
    }
```

How to get from Angular fromdata hear
controller:

```
[Route("postItem")]
[HttpPost]
public void addNewModelsImage([FromBody] IFormFile file)
{

    var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
    string sub = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.IndexOf(".") + 1);
    string path = "C:\\Users\\AVITAL\\Desktop\\הנדסאים\\angular\\my-first-project\\src\\assets\\image";
    file.CopyTo(System.IO.File.Create(path + file.FileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Route("postItem")]
[HttpPost]
public void addNewModelsImage([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    string sub = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.IndexOf(".") + 1);
    string path = "C:\\Users\\AVITAL\\Desktop\\הנדסאים\\angular\\my-first- 
  project\\src\\assets\\image\\";
    file.CopyTo(System.IO.File.Create(path + file.FileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To upload image files to your Web API from Angular client app, you can refer to the following example.

*On Angular client*

```
fileToUpload: FileList = null;

handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
  this.fileToUpload = files;
  console.log(this.fileToUpload.length);
}

uploadFile() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  Array.from(this.fileToUpload).forEach(file => {
    // set the key of formdata correctly 
    // based on the parameter name of your WebAPI action
    formData.append("file", file);
  });

  this.http
    .post("https://xxxx/api/model/postItem", formData)
    .subscribe(res => {
      alert("Uploaded!!");
    });
}
```

*Web API Action*

```
public class ModelController : ControllerBase
{
    private IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    public ModelController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    [Route("postItem")]
    [HttpPost]    
    public void addNewModelsImage([FromForm] List<IFormFile> file) // use List<IFormFile> for uploaded multiple files
    {

        //code logice here
```

Test Result

[image]

**Note:**

1) You can know details about "Static files in ASP.NET Core" from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1

2) If your client app and back-end service are hosting with different domain, you may need to enable CORS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1